# Включение списка, понимание итератора

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, итераторы

Допустим у меня есть вот два таких небольших включения, которые заполняют два разных списка при проверке на чётность и нечётность

```
no = [i for i in range(1, 20) if i % 2 == True]

yes = [i for i in range(1, 20) if i % 2 == False]

print(f"{no}\n{yes}")
```

В целом, я понимаю как это всё работает, но я не понимаю для чего нам это значение `i #<== for i in range...` До меня не доходит, для чего мы два раза указываем одну и ту же переменную для цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше включение аналогично такому циклу

```
yes = []
for i in range(1, 20):
    if i % 2 == False:
        yes.append(i)
```

То есть первое упоминание `i` - это то, что вы добавите в список.

```
[i for i in range(1, 20) if i % 2 == False]
 ^     ^
 |     Переменная цикла
 Возвращаемое значение
```

Вы можете вместо возвращаемого значения написать всё, что угодно. Например

```
[1 for i in range(1, 20) if i % 2 == False]
```

И тогда у вас получится список из единиц по количеству элементов сгенерированных включением. Или вы можете написать

```
[i / 2 for i in range(1, 20) if i % 2 == False]
```

И тогда в результирующем списке будут значения из диапазона делённые на 2.